# Should I keep my South migrations in version control?

Tags: django, version-control, django-south

I'm not sure if I should keep them around or not. The main reason I'm using `south` at the moment is to ease development changes to the model, though I suppose it will come in handy when I'm in production. Should I be keeping my local development migrations in my Git repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a technical answer, but if you:

- want to roll things back at any stage;
- need to keep a full record of all changes;
- are building up data in SQLite locally and using it remotely;

it might be a good idea. Why would you not?

Alternatively, you could maintain a separate branch for the South migrations.

Comment: I guess my question is that if I'm already keeping my model in version control and tracking its changes, why would I need to hold onto the migrations? I understand that when I deploy, it'll be essential to do a migration on the server, but the migrations on my local computer will be much more incremental. (ie: add a field to the User class, etc) I suppose I could just keep them in any case, hopefully it doesn't make things more complicated in the future.

Comment: Looks like you've made up your mind :-) OOI what database are you using?

Comment: SQLite for development, MySQL for production.

Comment: You would also want to keep them if you write any migrations by hand, maybe complicated Spatial queries.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should. At some point you won't be able to do schema migration without performing additional data migrations. And those are not auto generated.